# Are security/validation rules available for GCP Firestore in Datastore Mode?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I found [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) which describes how to use security rules for validation for GCP Firestore.

However, its not clear to me if these rules are only for Firestore Native Mode, for Firestore in Datastore Mode, or for both.

Are security/validation rules available for GCP Firestore in Datastore Mode?

Comment: Firestore in Datastore mode does not support any security rules. Security access for that has to be handled through IAM. You can check this documentation about **[IAM in](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam)** 

**[Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam)**.

Comment: Hi does my comment help ?